# Running python commands in a py/text file in Linux terminal using flask shell

Tags: linux, python

Is it possible to run a python file using flask shell similar to python? Similar to:

`flask shell myfile.py`

`flask shell -f myfile.py`

That's all I get when using `$ flask shell --help`:

```
Usage: flask shell [OPTIONS]

  Runs an interactive Python shell in the context of a given Flask
  application.  The application will populate the default namespace of this
  shell according to it's configuration.

  This is useful for executing small snippets of management code without
  having to manually configure the application.

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.
```

I've specified the following variables:

```
export FLASK_APP=run.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

Tool version Info:
 - Linux 3.10
 - Python 3.7.1
 - Flask 1.0.2

Comment: I'm tempted to write an answer containing simply 'yes'. Did you look at `flask shell --help`?

Comment: @Panki yes I did, please see the update

Comment: Did you specify what you want to run by setting the `FLASK_APP` environment variable?

Comment: @Panki I did that too